# SQL Stored Preocedure appears to not be receiving parametrs

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Can someone help me figure out why this is not working.

Here's the SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sGetPeriods @PeriodTypeID INT, @ParentPeriodID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SELECT PeriodID, Period
      FROM Periods
     WHERE CASE WHEN @PeriodTypeID IS NULL THEN 1
                WHEN @PeriodTypeID = PeriodTypeID THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END = 1
       AND CASE WHEN @ParentPeriodID IS NULL THEN 1
                WHEN @ParentPeriodID = ParentPeriodID THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END = 1
    ORDER BY Period
END
GO
```

Here's the C# code that calls the SP:

```
    private DataTable CmdExecuteToDataTable(SqlCommand objSQLCmd)
    {
        DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection objSQLConn = new SqlConnection(c_szSQLConnectionString))
        {
            objSQLConn.Open();
            objSQLCmd.Connection = objSQLConn;
            if (bLog)
            {
                //WriteLog("Connection: " + objSQLConn.ConnectionString);
                WriteLog("CmdExecuteToDataTable(" + objSQLCmd.CommandText + ")");
                for (int zz = 0; zz < objSQLCmd.Parameters.Count; zz++)
                {
                    WriteLog(objSQLCmd.Parameters[zz].ParameterName + ": " + objSQLCmd.Parameters[zz].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            SqlDataReader _r = objSQLCmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (_r.HasRows)
            {
                DataReaderAdapter _dra = new DataReaderAdapter();
                _dra.FillFromReader(dtReturn, _r);
            }
            _r.Close();
        }

        if (bLog)
        {
            WriteLog("\t" + "Returned: " + dtReturn.Rows.Count.ToString() + " rows.");
            WriteLog(("-").PadRight(80, '-'));
        }
        return dtReturn;
    }
```

And, here's the code that calls the above method:

```
    public DataTable GetPeriods(int iPeriodTypeID, int iParentPeriodID)
    {
        SqlCommand objSQLCmd = new SqlCommand("sGetPeriods");
        objSQLCmd.Parameters.Clear();
        if (iPeriodTypeID != 0)
            objSQLCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PeriodTypeID", iPeriodTypeID));
        if (iParentPeriodID != 0)
            objSQLCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentPeriodID", iParentPeriodID));
        return CmdExecuteToDataTable(objSQLCmd);
    }
```

Finally, here's the page code that calls the method above:

```
        int iPeriodTypeID = 1;
        int iParentPeriodID = 1;
        DataTable dtPeriods = clsDataLayer.GetPeriods(iPeriodTypeID, iParentPeriodID);
```

When the page loads, I get

```
Procedure or function 'sGetPeriods' expects parameter '@PeriodTypeID', which was not supplied.
```

Yet, the parameter IS supplied as verified by the LOG file entry:

```
8/19/2011 8:44:16 AM: CmdExecuteToDataTable(sGetPeriods)
8/19/2011 8:44:16 AM: @PeriodTypeID: 1
8/19/2011 8:44:16 AM: @ParentPeriodID: 1
```

Somehow, the stored procedure is not getting the values passed with the SQL Command object.
Any ideas?

FYI, when I defined the SP Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sGetPeriods @PeriodTypeID INT = NULL, @ParentPeriodID INT = NULL
```

the Procedure executes but returns ALL rows as if it had not received any parameters.

I tried wrapping the code within a using(sqlcommand sqlcmd = objSLQCmd) but that did not help.

Thanks for any pointers,

John

Comment: How do you know it's not getting the parameters?

Comment: Also LOL @ 6 questions, no votes, no accepted answers, and an essay question here.

Comment: Try removing those conditions when creating the command and assigning parameters.

Comment: Pease check the datatypes in all cases

Comment: Why bother adding a comment if you're not contributing to the answer?

Comment: No need to remove the conditionals as I already know that the parameters are being passed because they are printed in the log. If they were not being passed, there would be nothing to print iin the log. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Finally, I apologize for not accepting, voting, etc. Still new enough to not know the correct protocol.   I can't even find anyplace to vote/ accept.

Comment: try creating the sqlparameter explicitly.pass the datatype also.

Comment: Expand the section of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on "How do I ask questions here", to learn about voting and accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx) of the SqlCommand to [StoredProcedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx).

At the moment, it interpreting it as a textual query (literally `sGetPeriods`). For a text query, you have to include the appropriate parameters in the text of the query, which you're not doing.

It's unfortunate that, if you give SQL a query batch that starts with a stored procedure name, it treats it as if an `exec` is present before that. It would have been a far more obvious error message if this wasn't so.

Comment: That was it. I can't believe I missed that - especially since it's bit me in the behind before!  Thanks so much for your help.